# How to get response data to be used outside function

Tags: javascript

How do I get response data to be used outside function?

```
var myVar;

        uploadService.getUploadFolderId(folderId).then(function(response){      
            console.log("Show docs id", response.data); // I get output :)
            myVar = response;
            return myVar;

        }).$promise;

console.log("show", myVar) // output: undefined
```

I did some reading and practices about global function and function hoisting but I still could not get it to work. Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) API in javascript. Essentially you:

1. Create your local variable (`value` below)
2. Create your `Promise`
3. Perform some long running task in your promise, and call `resolve` when you have what you want
4. Pass an object into the `resolve` handler that you want to preserve (expose outside of the `Promise)
5. Utilize the `then(...)` handler on the `Promise` and extract the object you resolved earlier

Example:

```
var value = 'Foo';

var promise = new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('Bar')
    }, 1000);
  });

promise.then(function(val) {
  value = val;
  console.log(value); // Bar
});
```

Comment: `console.log(value); // Bar` show output inside promise but outside of it show `Foo`? How do I use the output inside promise outside of it? Thanks.

Comment: @sg552 You don't. You must rely on the promise to resolve in order to use it. The whole point of asynchronous operations is you wait until you get the response, and then act on it. `value` above is set to the result of the promise resolution, so you can use that *outside of the promise*... but you need to wait for it to resolve first.